# Solve $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}$ so as to $\varphi=f_1-f_2$ for any function $\varphi$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let be $f_1:A_2\rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $f_2:A_2\rightarrow\Bbb R$ two function defined in open sets of $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R$ and thus we suppose that there exist a function $\varphi:A\rightarrow\Bbb R$ defined in an open set of $\Bbb R^n$ such that the equation

$$
\varphi(x)=f_1(x,y)-f_2(x,y)
$$
holds for all $(x,y)\in A_1\cap A_2$ such that $x\in A$. So if $\phi:A\times\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$  is the function defined by the equation
$$
\phi(x,y):=\varphi(x)
$$
for all $(x,y)\in A\times\Bbb R$ then it would be
$$
\phi(x,y)=f_1(x,y)-f_2(x,y)
$$
for all $(x,y)\in (A_1\cap A_2)\cap(A\times\Bbb R)$ so that deriving this equation we can conclude that
$$
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}
$$
provided that all function can be derived. Now I would like to know how procede conversely: that is, how solve the last equation so as to the first equation holds knowing **only** the function $\varphi$? So could someone help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I do not understand your question fully. I will try to give you an answer nevertheless, please let me know if it adresses your needs.

**First attempt: starting from the differential equation**

Basically starting from the last line

$$
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}
$$

it is just an application of the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) in $y$-direction. Indeed, integration (and treating the $x$ variables simply as parameters) we directly obtain

$$
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}\Rightarrow f_1=f_2+c(x)
$$
Note that there is no out of the box constraint on the regularity of $c$ and $c$ can also "jump" in $y$ direction if for fixed $x$ the $y$-domain is not a single intervall.

**Second attempt: starting from $\varphi$, try to retrieve $f_1,f_2$**

If we assume $\phi(x)$ is known, *any* $f_1$ will be a solution by simply setting $f_2(x,y)=f_1(x,y)-\varphi(x)$.

Comment: So I want solve the equation $$\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}$$ with respect the constraint $$f_1-f_2=\varphi$$ where $\varphi$ is an assigned function, that's all.

Comment: Not exactly. $f_1-f_2=\varphi$ IS the solution to the differential equation.

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I did not explain well: only $\varphi$ is knew whereas $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not knew.

Comment: In fact in the question I asked how to procede **conversely** when **only** $\varphi$ is knew.

Comment: I tried to add an answer to that but please try to clarify what you actually want to know in the original question.

Comment: I edited the question. I read your second attempt: the solution does not seem incorrect but before to accept the answer I would await any time to understand if there are other possible solutions. Anyway I think I will upvoted the answer.